# number of AppBarButton in PrimaryCommands

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

Is there any limit on number of AppBarButtons that can be added in PrimaryCommands in BottomBar. I am trying to add 5th button in bottom bar but its now showing up on device. Any workaround to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In Windows Phone 8.1 (also in 8.0) you can have up to 4 items in *Application Bar* (primary commands, note that you can add more options to *SecondaryCommands* which will show up once ellipsis is clicked). If you need more, then I you will have to create your own control that will mimic the behavior of application bar.

For more about application bar in 8.1 see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh781230.aspx) and [guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465302.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Have done something that will at-least serve the purpose for me.

Comment: I don't need any secondary command and "..." so I simply added AppBarButtons at the bottom of page in a grid with black background.